# Converting usage of VB6 err object to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, migration

Below is my vb6 code how can i convert this into c#, Actually i'm getting confusion in that handling of err in if condition.

```
Function FilterDuplicates(Arr As Variant) As Long
Dim col As Collection, Index As Long, dups As Long
Set col = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For Index = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    col.Add 0, CStr(Arr(Index))
    If err Then
        Arr(Index) = Empty
        dups = dups + 1
        err.Clear
    ElseIf dups Then
        Arr(Index - dups) = Arr(Index)
        Arr(Index) = Empty
    End If
Next
FilterDuplicates = dups      End Function
```

Below is my C# Code which i tried and here actually i'm unable to handle this If condition part.

```
        private long FilterDuplicates(string[] Arr)
    {
        Collection col = new Collection();
        long Index=0;
        long dups =0;    
        try
        {
            for (Index = Arr.GetLowerBound(0); Index <= Arr.GetUpperBound(0); Index++)
            {
                col.Add(0, Conversion.Str(Arr[Index]));
                if (Information.Err)
                {
                    Arr[Index] = null;
                    dups += 1;
                    err.Clear;
                }
                else if (dups != 0)
                {
                    Arr[Index - dups] = Arr[Index];
                    Arr[Index] = null;
                }
            }
            return dups;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: i have uploaded my C# code also please have a loop of that @JohnB

Comment: It's usually best to be specific about the exception types you intend to catch. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions) and [more docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions) for some examples.

Comment: sure you can handle an error and log it or whatever, then use the `contine`.

Comment: I don't know how to handle the exception with a for loop, actually i want to increase the count of dups and have to make a error handler clear so it will run until for loop

Comment: `try {...} catch {...}` will catch exceptions in the block of code the try is around. Once an exception is thrown, execution moves out of the try block and doesn't re-enter it. If you want the loop to continue, you need to move the try/catch logic inside the loop. Note however, that you don't typically want to control program flow using exceptions - if you can perform a low-cost check before causing an exception, it's better.

Comment: @JohnB okay that means i have to handle the try{} catch {} inside the for loop right ?

Comment: yes for sure...

Comment: Am I correct you only want to return the count of the duplicates? Using a try catch is not needed then..

Comment: What is the initial routine suppose to do? Often it's by far easier to *implement* a method than *convert* it: e.g. to count duplicates `Arr.Length() - Arr.Distinct().Count();`, get rid of duplicates: `Arr.Distinct.ToArray();` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Often it's easier to *implement* the routine than *convert* it. It seems, you want

1. Change each duplcate (i.e. second, third etc value) into `null`
2. Count all such changes

If it's your case, you can try

```
 private static long FilterDuplicates(string[] Arr) {
   HashSet<string> appeared = new HashSet<string>();

   long result = 0;  

   for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; ++i)       
     if (!appeared.Add(Arr[i])) {
       result += 1;

       Arr[i] = null;
     }

   return result;
 }
```